# PHP header('Location: '); problem on certain servers on our company network

Tags: php

I have tried:

```
header('Location: http://www.google.com/');
die();
```

It works on Godaddy and fails on both Ipage and Startlogic on my network at work using FireFox,IE and Chrome. They work at the Public Library on all three servers using Firefox. The person doing our IT thinks it might be a cisco conflict, but has been unable to resolve it.

Is this a common enough problem I should avoid PHP 302 redirects

Any ideas on how to resolve this.

** I added to a comment below and should have had it up here
"Is there a better term than hangs. Anyway it hangs whenever I execute a script without output."
Godaddy works fine the other two will keep going and going until they time out

Comment: What does "fails" actually mean here? What is the context (in terms of request data, request method etc.) to this call in those cases?

Comment: Can you access `http://www.google.com` normally, typing the address into your browser?

Comment: yes google works and it says waiting in the bottom left hand corner so hangs might be better than fails

Answer (score 3):

Your question is not completely well-formed. I mean, we all expect at least an error message or a bad behaviour rather a simple "fail".

Anyway, I suspect you just get a blank page, hiding a warning saying that the headers were already sent. This is a common problem in PHP, believe me.

In order to turn errors on, you must either configure your `php.ini` or enable all errors via code so you can inspects any alert generated by PHP.

Mostly, this problem (which occurs on some systems and doesn't occur on others) is caused by UTF-8 `BOM`, which is the 3 bytes that you don't see before the `<?php` at script beginning. This is usually caused by writing the PHP script in Notepad or an UTF-8 editor and executing the code in a non-UTF8 environment (I think Linux prefer ASCII is that right?)

Anyway, you could try editing the file with a native editor from console, or from Wordpad, or better Notepad++, and save it as ASCII.

If that's the problem, you'll solve it. The reason behind this is that PHP reads the `BOM` and prints it to HTTP response, after which you can set no more HTTP header. That's it.

Comment: I am using netbeans and I changed the code ini_set('log_errors',0); ini_set('error_log', 'syslog'); ini_set('display_errors','1'); ini_set('display_startup_errors','1'); header('Location: http://www.google.com/'); die(); /* still hangs */

Comment: Is there a better term than hangs. Anyway it hangs whenever I execute a script without output.

Comment: Hanging means that you see a blank page and the browser keeps waiting for data. If you get the blank page but the browser stops then it's not a hang

Comment: well haning is the right then. On other scripts where there it is not being redirected somewhere else if there is no output it hangs. All i have to do is add echo ' '; /*it needs something between the single quotes*/ Again godaddy does not hang without the echo

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried building a correct, complete HTTP header?

Above header is very minimal, and lacks the status code - which should be the minimum an HTTP response has. Most clients and proxies will guess what you mean, generating a correct response might help.
Choose the appropriate 3xx error, like

```
header('Status: 301 moved permanently');
```

and possibly

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

if you are using UTF-8 (the answer concerning the BOM is another likely candidate).